# Merge list in parallel run in R

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing

I have a function which I will iterate 40000 times, I want to make it parallel, have tried with the library doParallel with a certain batchsize 200.

The output is in a list and I want to accumulate to sum elementwise. Each object in the output is pretty large which is the reason to why I have to divide it into batches.

However the run time becomes very slow as I run more than one batch, 1 single batch take 11 s run time, 10 batches take 160 seconds. Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong.

```
library(doParallel)
myCluster <- makeCluster(3, # number of cores to use
                         type = "PSOCK") # type of cluster
registerDoParallel(myCluster)
for(i in 1:1){
    result = foreach(j=((i-1)*batch_size+1):(i*batch_size)) %dopar% {
        some_function(input_data[j,])
    }
    result_batch_tmp <- Reduce("+",result)
    if(i==1) result_batch <- list(result_batch_tmp) 
    else result_batch <- c(result_batch,result_batch2)
    rm(result)
    rm(result_batch_tmp) 
}
stopCluster(myCluster)
```

Comment: maybe you could give example of your data and what are you calculating? `some_function` is not quite explanatory..

Comment: I am calculating the future cash flows per contract, the function some_function calculate the cash flow from one row in the input_data. In the end I want the total cash flow

Comment: you probably could do that without foreach..

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help you we need a [mcve]. You can easily generate random data of the right shape as input.

Comment: minem can you please explain or send a link? Ralf this is my first post, I appologize for the code, I try to edit it so it become more readable

Comment: You use batchs to prevent memory problems?

Comment: Yes thats what I try todo, but it seem like the result from the batch stay in the memory when I send in the next batch and it become slow. 1 batch take 11 seconds, 2 batches 26 seconds and 5 batches 170 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

### Data

```
input_data <- as.matrix(iris[rep(1:150, 1000), rep(1:4, 100)])
dimnames(input_data) <- list(NULL, NULL)
batch_size <- 1e3
some_function <- mean
```

### Computation

```
library(doParallel)
myCluster <- makeCluster(3, # number of cores to use
                         type = "PSOCK") # type of cluster
registerDoParallel(myCluster)

batchs <- 1

# Your solution
system.time({
  result_all <- foreach(i = seq_len(batchs)) %do% {
    ind.batch  <- ((i-1)*batch_size+1):(i*batch_size)
    result <- foreach(j = ind.batch) %dopar% {
      some_function(input_data[j, ])
    }
    Reduce("+", result)
  }
  result_all <- Reduce("+", result_all)
})

# My solution
system.time({
  result_all <- foreach(i = seq_len(batchs)) %do% {
    ind.batch  <- ((i-1)*batch_size+1):(i*batch_size)
    data.batch <- input_data[ind.batch, ]
    result <- foreach(j = seq_along(ind.batch)) %dopar% {
      some_function(data.batch[j, ])
    }
    Reduce("+", result)
  }
  result_all <- Reduce("+", result_all)
})

stopCluster(myCluster)
```

### Timings:

- 1  -> 0.35 vs 3.5
- 10 -> 3.9  vs 35.9
- 30 -> 11.3 vs 106

### Explanation:

I couldn't fully reproduce your problem but I think that if you use `input_data[j,]` in the `foreach`, you will copy all the data to each cluster. This is why I create a `data.batch` and then apply the `foreach`-parallel loop.

Comment: thank you. It is a better solution then what I wrote but it give the same performance for me, it seem like R does run out of memory because it become significantly slower after just 5 iterations. 1iteration 11 sec, 2 iterations 26 sec, 5 iterations 155 sec. Is it common that the memory become full during foreach loops?

Comment: Please provide the size of the data and your function. It works well on my computer.

Comment: The size of my input data is a matrix of 40000 rows and 23 columns where one row conain the input information. The output from one person is a 1400*25 matrix. However I just need the sum from all the matrixes elementwise and thats is why I use reduce. I dont understand how I can see the size of a function.

Comment: I want your function, not the size of it. Okay, I understand now, I thought the problem was with the size of the input data but in fact the problem with the size of the output..

Comment: I have tried to use rm() and gc() in order to free some memory. My function is rather big, I dont know if it will give any relevant information, but it creates a cashflow based on the info from the input data

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem at all. Even when computing 30, 100 and 400 batchs of size 100, with each row outputing a matrix of size 1400*25, I get linear timings with number of batchs.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers, so then I should probably look into the function and see if there are any leakage of memory there?

Comment: You should try to make your function simpler (even if you don't get precisely the same output) while keeping your problem. When the function is simple enough, post it here so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi again, I have now removed most of the code but what I attach is having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have now removed most of the code, but what I attach is having the same problem, it becomes much slower as I increase the number of runs

```
step_calc_date <- function(calc_date){
  if(substr(calc_date,5,6)==12) return(floor(calc_date/10000)*10000+10101)
  else return(calc_date+100)
}


some_function <- function(input){
  calc_date<- 20180401
  t=0
  for(i in 1:1400){
    t=t+1
    calc_date=step_calc_date(calc_date)#step 1 period
    state <- t(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))
    state_prev_period = state
  }
  BE_period = rep(1,120*12+1)
  rm(input)
  return(BE_period[1])
}
```

Comment: Don't vandalize your own posts; if you plan on updating it, you can delete it, edit, and undelete, or just let it stay in its current form until you edit